# Int() doesn't convert from String to Optional Integer (Swift)

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I'm new at programming and started with Swift. The first issue I came along with is the following:

I have 4 variables

```
var a = "345"

var b = "30.6"

var c = "74hf2"

var d = "5"
```

I need to count the sum of Integers (if not integer, it will turn to nil)

```
if Int(a) != nil {
  var aNum = Int(ar)!
} 

if Int (b) != nil {
  var bNum = Int (b)! 
}
```

and so on..

As far as I understand, the Int() should convert each element into an Optional Integer.

Then I should use forced unwrapping by convertin the Int? to Int and only then I can use it for my purposes. But instead, when I count the sum of my variables, the compiler sums them as Strings.

```
 var sum = aNum + bNum + cNum + dNum
```

Output:

```
  34530.674hf25
```

Why my variables, which are declared as strings and then converted into optional integers with Int(), didn't work?

Comment: Where do you "count a sum"? – Btw, `var 6 = "30.6"` clearly demonstrates that this is not your real code.

Comment: You should take a moment to read the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) section of the Swift book.

Comment: FYI - your four `String` variables are not optionals. But that's not relevant to your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to Int in Swift 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064294/string-to-int-in-swift-3-0)

Comment: Your  `if Int(a) != nil {  var aNum = Int(ar)! }` assigns the integer to a **local variable** `aNum` whose scope is just the if-block. Apparently you have another `aNum` variable (probably a String)  which you don't show and which is "added" in `var sum = aNum + bNum + cNum + dNum`.

Comment: @MartinR, now it's clear, thank you very much!

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code. Show the code that sums your different ints together.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has typos that make it hard to tell what you are actually trying to do:

Assuming your 2nd variable should be `b`, as below:

```
var a = "345"
var b = "30.6"
var c = "74hf2"
var d = "5"

///Then you can use code like this:

var sum = 0

if let aVal = Int(a) { sum += aVal }

if let bVal = Int(b) { sum += bVal }

if let cVal = Int(c) { sum += cVal }

if let dVal = Int(d) { sum += dVal }

print(sum)
```

That prints `350` since only `345` and `5` are valid Int values.

Comment: Th code above uses `if let` optional binding. You should read up on optional binding. It lets you create a new variable from an optional if the optional is not nil, and then execute the body of the `if` statement. If the optional contains `nil` the body of the `if` is skipped

Comment: I know about optional binding and it worked in this case, I tried. But the thing is I want to understand, why forced unwrapping doesn't work here. Why doesn't Int() convert the variable type into optional Integer initially?